# Comparing user input values

Tags: java, input

I am not sure why but when I get a string from the user, I cannot compare it in an `if statement` but when I try to print it, it works fine.

Part of my code:

```
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         while (true) {
             String userInput;
             int rowInput, colInput;
             printBoard(board);
             System.out.print("Move: ");

             userInput = in.next();

             // shift board right on a row
             if (userInput == "r") {
                 System.out.print("row #: \r");
                 rowInput = in.nextInt();
                 moveRight(--rowInput, board);
             }
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (userInput.equals("r"))
```

`==` is used to comp‍‍‍‍‍‍‍are the `address` and `equals` is used to‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ compare ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍contents.

Answer (score 1):

I should be using **equals** instead of **==**.

So it would lead to:

```
...

if (userInput.equals("r"))

...
```